# How to serialize and deserialize complex nested json Unity?

Tags: c#, android, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have the following json

```
{
  "android_play_store_link": "xyz",
  "ios_app_store_link": "",
  "sticker_packs": [
    {
      "identifier": "1",
      "name": "abc",
      "publisher": "Jane Doe",
      "tray_image_file": "xyz.png",
      "image_data_version":"1",
      "avoid_cache":false,
      "publisher_email":"",
      "publisher_website": "",
      "privacy_policy_website": "",
      "license_agreement_website": "",
      "stickers": [
        {
          "image_file": "abc.webp",
          "emojis": ["☕",""]
        },
        {
          "image_file": "cdf.webp",
          "emojis": ["",""]
        },
        {
          "image_file": "efg.webp",
          "emojis": ["☕",""]
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have no acquaintance with json until now, How can i deserialize this ?

I know how to do the basic read and write code from persistent data path of unity. But how do i process this json ?

My main goal is as the player wins a level, a new key and value would be added to the "stickers" attribute, Also after some levels I want to add changes to the sticker packs attribute later.

Plus how will i modify the value of image data version in a specific sticker pack item ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on your example you'd need 4 classes. Emoji, Sticker, Sticker Pack, and some class name which encompasses the other 3 as a whole. Then you would deserialize into the class type which encompasses the others. You can use attributes in your class like `DataContract` and `DataMember` if using C#'s built in namespaces or you can import Nuget package `NewtonSoft Json`. Please see these two links for information: .Net way: (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/), NewtonSoft Json: (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)

Comment: As to your second question about modifying image data in a sticker pack item, you'd `deserialize` the `json` to a C# object, modify the value of the required sticker pack item, then `serialize` to `json` and save the `json` string.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json library to deserialize and serialize. Find below the respective C# class.

```
public class Sticker
{
    public string image_file { get; set; }
    public IList<string> emojis { get; set; }
}

public class StickerPack
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    public string tray_image_file { get; set; }
    public string image_data_version { get; set; }
    public bool avoid_cache { get; set; }
    public string publisher_email { get; set; }
    public string publisher_website { get; set; }
    public string privacy_policy_website { get; set; }
    public string license_agreement_website { get; set; }
    public IList<Sticker> stickers { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string android_play_store_link { get; set; }
    public string ios_app_store_link { get; set; }
    public IList<StickerPack> sticker_packs { get; set; }
}
```

**Code to Deserialize:**

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, It was typo

Comment: Any significance of using IList than using normal lists?